# showing google maps on android wear devices

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment, wear-os

I have developed an app to show ATM machines in your area. It works on my android phone but when I try to launch it on my android wearable watch it crashes. With the error "Binary XML File line #2 Error inflating class fragment" Any help is much appreciated.

Here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

and my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private String[] places;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Location loc;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    static String distance;
    public static final String PREF = "MyPrefs";
    public static final String DISTANCE = "distance";

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sp = this.getSharedPreferences(PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        distance = sp.getString(DISTANCE, "1000");

        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        currentLocation();
        places=new String[1];
        places[0]="ATM";
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    private class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Place>> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        private Context context;
        private String places;
        private double longitude;
        private double latitude;

        public GetPlaces(Context context, String places) {
            this.context = context;
            this.places = places;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Place> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Location location = lm
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(result.get(i).getName())
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(result.get(i).getLatitude(), result
                                        .get(i).getLongitude()))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.pin))
                        .snippet(result.get(i).getVicinity()));
            }
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)) // Sets the center of the map to
                    // Mountain View
                    .zoom(14) // Sets the zoom
                    .tilt(30) // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build(); // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }



        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Place> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            PlacesService service = new PlacesService(
                    "xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            ArrayList<Place> findPlaces = service.findPlaces(loc.getLatitude(), 
                    loc.getLongitude(), places, distance); 

            for (int i = 0; i < findPlaces.size(); i++) {

                Place placeDetail = findPlaces.get(i);
                Log.e(TAG, "places : " + placeDetail.getName());
            }
            return findPlaces;
        }

    }



    private void currentLocation() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        String provider = locationManager
                .getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location == null) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, listener);
        } else {
            loc = location;
            new GetPlaces(MainActivity.this, places[0].toLowerCase().replace(
                    "-", "_")).execute();
            Log.e(TAG, "location : " + location);
        }

    }

    private LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.e(TAG, "location update : " + location);
            loc = location;
            locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
        }
    };


}
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `MapFragment` and `GoogleMap` (along with the entirely of the Google Maps Android API) is currently not supported on Android Wear devices.